# Display table titles from nested list shows to much

Tags: jsf, datatable

I'm writing a blog, and I want to display from database dataTable with 2 columns, in one column I would like to have post title, and in other I want post content, but when I try to implement that in my page, the only result I get is that in post title column is displayed all post titles for every row. I would like to ask you, how could I achieve my goal.
Now i have

```
title1 title2 ... | content1 
title1 title2 ... | content2 
etc
```

but I would like to have

```
title 1| content1 <br>
title2 | content2 <br>
```

Here is my **index.xhtml** code to display dataTable

```
<h:dataTable value="#{postView.postList}" 
                     var="k"
                     styleClass="table"
                     headerClass="tableHeader"
                     rowClasses="tableContent"
                     >
            <h:column>
                <h:dataTable value="#{postView.postList}" var="t">
                    <h:column>
                        #{t.title}
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </h:column> 
            <h:column>
               #{k.postContent}               
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>
```

Here is my **controller**

```
package ManagePost;

import Entities.Post;
import FacadeDAO.PostFacade;
import FacadeDAO.UserFacade;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PostView implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private PostFacade postDAO;

    private List<Post> postList;
    private String title;
    private String content;

    public PostView() {

    }

    public List<Post> getPostList() {
        return postList;
    }

    public void setPostList(List<Post> postList) {
        this.postList = postList;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        postList = postDAO.showAll();
    }

    public String validate() {
        Post post = postDAO.checkIfExist(title);
        if (post == null) {
            Post newPost = new Post();
            newPost.setTitle(title);
            newPost.setPostContent(content);
            try {
                postDAO.add(newPost);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return "loginPage";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

And the last, **PostDao**

```
public List<Post> showAll() {
        List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Post> result = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Post.findAll", Post.class).getResultList();

        postList.addAll(result);

        return postList;
    }
```

Comment: Please take care of good tagging... By adding glassfish-5 you e.g. state it is no problem in earlier versions of Glasdfish or in Wildfly. And This issue is not JSF-2.2 specific. Tags are for where problems are, not what you use.

Comment: Uhmmm... You iterate over the same list twice!!! That cannot be good

Comment: @Kukeltje You're right, sorry for that, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are displaying all the titles in an embedded datatable. You should remove the nested datatable tag:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{postView.postList}" 
             var="k"
             styleClass="table"
             headerClass="tableHeader"
             rowClasses="tableContent"
             >
    <h:column>
        #{k.title}
    </h:column> 
    <h:column>
       #{k.postContent}               
    </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```